# Como atribuir o resultado de um while/for em uma lista para que possa operar com os valores

Tags: python, lista, for, int

```
n = int(input("what range?"))

f1=0
f2=1

cont = 1
while cont <= n:
    f3 = f1 + f2
    f1 = f2
    f2 = f3
    if f3 % 2 == 0:
       print(f3) # Como eu somo os valores de f3 ou transformo ele em uma lista?

    cont += 1
```

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: Vinicius, não entendi bem, mas seria isso aqui que você queria? https://repl.it/repls/DarkcyanMintcreamDataset

Comment: ```
```   if f3 % 2 == 0:
       print(sum(f3)) 
```
#  quero que o resultado desse while me gere uma lista e nao uma sequencia para que eu possa os termos contidos dentro dela . 

    cont += 1
`

Answer (score 1):

```
n = int(input('What range? '))

f1 = 0
f2 = 2
lista = []
cont = 0

while cont < n:
    f3 = f1 + f2
    f1 = f2
    f2 = f3
    if f3 % 2 == 0:
        lista.append(f3)  # crio a lista dos valores
    cont += 1

cont = 0  # zero o valor para fazer outro while
total = 0  # crio uma variável para somar todos os valores da lista

while cont < n:
    print(lista[cont])  # exibo a lista criada
    total += lista[cont]  # somo os valores da lista
    cont += 1

print('A soma dos valores é: ', total)  # exibo a soma dos valores da lista
```

Comment: Muito obrigado !!!